# Trouble setting up bees with machineguns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-testing, boto

I'm trying to setup bees with machine guns to load test a server.

I've followed all the steps explained in the [Readme](https://github.com/newsapps/beeswithmachineguns).

As far as I can tell, it is finding my .pem file and my boto config, but when I try the following command:

```
$ bees up -s 1 -g public -k loadtest
```

I get the following error:

> The security group 'public' does not exist in default VPC
>   'vpc-934dc8f6'

The strange thing is that my security group does not have any group with a vpc-id of 'vpc-934dc8f6'

Am I missing something? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I venture the guess that you might look at different [AWS regions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html) here: the 'default' AWS region is different depending on the tool in use and also changed over time. In particular, it used to be `us-east-1` almost everywhere, but the [AWS Management Console](https://aws.amazon.com/console/) defaults to `us-west-2` now for many customers, IIRC.

Accordingly, it is all but uncommon to accidentally look at a different region in the console than with the tool in use for interacting with the API, like `bees` from [Bees with Machine Guns](https://github.com/newsapps/beeswithmachineguns) here for example, which uses the [AWS SDK for Python (Boto)](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/) in turn.

In other words, the *default VPC 'vpc-934dc8f6'* most definitely exists in the AWS region `bees` is actually targeting by default (in your environment), if reported like that, which just happens to be not the one you would like and expect to use apparently.

Comment: Thank you! I've found the illusive VPC id by changing the zone to us-east-1 as you suggested.